# How to get screen shot of expo screen?

Tags: react-native, screenshot, expo

I am new to the expo and running expo project in the expo app for testing. I can see many people sharing their screenshot of App on the web? I know there is an android/iPhone app to get a screenshot from the phone.

Is there any easier way to get the screenshot of the expo from the PC/Mac?

Answer (score 0):

Using Android File Manager is only way to go to

Answer (score 0):

-If you are using a Mac and testing the app on iPhone Simulator
Press Cmd+S in order to save a screenshot. It will be saved on Desktop